# Get selected value and display to another page

Tags: php, html, oracle

This select will display a list of users with their ID, fname and lname. 
How to do, so if I chose on user from the list, and then I click the button "send", it will redirect to another page, and in the second page it will display the user that I selected?

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select user_id, fname,lname from users");
oci_execute($stid);

    echo "<select size = '5'>";

    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!= false) {
        echo "<option value=$row[user_id]>".$row['user_id'] . " " .$row['fname'] 
        . " " . $row['lname'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";




<form method="post" action="send.php">

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">

</form>
```

Comment: You should put `select` element into the `form`.

Comment: @chaska, sorry that didn't help a lot :(

Comment: add `action="destinationpage.php"` to the form and in `destinationpage.php` use `<?php var_dump( $_REQUEST[] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the form method to `get` rather than post. You also need to give the `select` element a `name` attribute, so it's value is sent.

```php
<form method="get" action="send.php">
<?php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select user_id, fname,lname from users");
    oci_execute($stid);
    echo "<select name='id' size = '5'>";
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!= false){
        echo "<option value=$row[user_id]>".$row['user_id'] . " " .$row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "</option>";
    }echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send"></p>
</form>
```

Submitting your form will send you browser to:

```
send.php?send=send&id=<id>
```

Then, in `send.php` you can get the user id from the `$_GET` superglobal.

```php
$userId = $_GET['id']
```

Comment: is important where form should be? can she begin after $stid?

Comment: The `form` must wrap the select element that is echo'd by the `$stid` block of code.

Comment: where i put this :send.php?send=send&id=<id>

Comment: You don't need to add that anywhere. That's just an example of the URL the form will send you to.

Comment: I'm thinking where to begin with <form method="get" action="send.php">
cause $stid= oci_parce, it's not the begining of the code

Comment: You need to place the `<form method="get" action="send.php">` before the line with `$stid= oci_parce`

Comment: should I echo it? cause it's html in php

Comment: Yes, you need to echo it.

Comment: I don't know if it passed to second page, it is redirected there but I have error: Undefined index:id in /var/....